# Equalise the number of files with windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a script that is designed to count the number of files with a value in the filename (****_1.jpg), compare it with the number of files with another name (****_2.jpg) and delete the larger number of files so the number of files are equal for each type.

This is what I've got so far

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions
set count1=0
set count2=0
for %%f in (.\seq\*_1.jpg) do set /a count1+=1
echo "1 " %count1%
for %%f in (.\seq\*_2.jpg) do set /a count2+=1
echo "2 " %count2%


if %count1% gtr %count2% (
    set /a count=%count2%-%count1%
    for /l %%A in (1,1,%count%) do echo "%count2% + %%A _1.jpg"
)
if %count2% gtr %count1% (
    set /a count=%count2%-%count1%
    for /l %%A in (1,1,%count%) do echo "%count1% + %%A _2.jpg"
)

endlocal
```

I can get the counts, I make it to my if statements and then nothing happens. What am I missing?
For now I'm trying to echo a list of files I'm about to delete.

Comment: You are inside a parenethesized code block. You need to enable delayed expansion and reference your variables with exclamation points instead of percent symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the need for ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION, there really is no record of file names from either set. The "count" cannot be used to create the filename, can it?

I put in some code at the top to create a test set. Always referencing THEDIR obviates the need to hardcode a directory name in many places.

When you think it will work, remove `echo` from the DEL command line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "THEDIR=.\seqtest"
if not exist "%THEDIR%" (mkdir "%THEDIR%")
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 5) do (echo %%i >"%THEDIR%\file_%%i_1.jpg")
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 7) do (echo %%i >"%THEDIR%\file_%%i_2.jpg")

set count1=0
set count2=0

for %%f in ("%THEDIR%\*_1.jpg") do set /a count1+=1
echo "1 " %count1%

for %%f in ("%THEDIR%\*_2.jpg") do set /a count2+=1
echo "2 " %count2%

if %count1% gtr %count2% (
    set /a count=%count2%-%count1%
    set /a "dcount=0"

    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`dir /b "%THEDIR%\*_1.jpg"`) do (
        echo DEL "%%~f"

        set /a "dcount+=1"
        if !dcount! EQU !count! (goto Outa2)
    )
    for /l %%A in (1,1,%count%) do echo "%count2% + %%A _1.jpg"
)

if %count2% gtr %count1% (
    set /a count=%count2%-%count1%
    set /a "dcount=0"

    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`dir /b "%THEDIR%\*_2.jpg"`) do (
        echo DEL "%%~f"

        set /a "dcount+=1"
        if !dcount! EQU !count! (goto Outa2)
    )
)
:Outa2

:TheEnd
exit /b 0
```

If you want to delete any _1 file that does not exist as an _2 file and vice versa, you could loop over the _1 files and delete any for which no _2 file exists. Then, loop over the _2 files and delete any for which no _1 file exists.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`dir /b "%THEDIR%\*_1.jpg"`) DO (
    set "FN=%%~f"
    set "BASE=!FN:~0,-6!"
    if not exist "%THEDIR%\!BASE!_2.jpg" (echo DEL "%THEDIR%\!BASE!_1.jpg")
)

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in (`dir /b "%THEDIR%\*_2.jpg"`) DO (
    set "FN=%%~f"
    set "BASE=!FN:~0,-6!"
    if not exist "%THEDIR%\!BASE!_1.jpg" (echo DEL "%THEDIR%\!BASE!_2.jpg")
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is kind of working.. but not quite right.  In the test I'm doing there are 2096 1s and 4383 2s. I'm expecting it to start deleting at 2097_2.jpg and finish at 4383_2.jpg but instead it starts deleting at 1893_2.jpg and finishes at 02287_2.jpg. I think that last delete function is getting confused. I was trying to construct the delete command using the number and creating the filename based on starting at 2s-1s.

Comment: Are you saying that the file names are numbered incrementally in each _1 and _2 group?

Comment: yes that's right.. that second answer seems to make sense.

Comment: The DIR and FOR commands will not list files numerically like Windows Explorer does.

Comment: The OP did not specify which files to delete. Only that the count should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this problem, you have *two lists of files* and you want to delete files from the larger list so both lists have the same number of files. Right? For example:

```
1_1.jpg    1_2.jpg
2_1.jpg    2_2.jpg
3_1.jpg    3_2.jpg
           4_2.jpg
           5_2.jpg
```

In previous example you want to delete `4_2.jpg` and `5_2.jpg`, correct? If the first list is the larger one, the files must be deleted from it; if both lists have the same number of files, no files be deleted. This solution do that:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Enter to the folder with files
cd seq

rem Get the first list of files
dir /B *_1.jpg > first.txt

rem Merge the first list...
< first.txt (

   rem ... with the second list
   for %%f in (*_2.jpg) (

      rem For each file in second list, read a file from first list
      set "first=" & set /P "first="

      if not defined first ( rem The second list is larger: cut it
         ECHO del "%%f"
      )

   )

   rem If still are files in first list, it is larger: cut it
   for /F "delims=" %%f in ('findstr "^"') do ECHO del "%%f"

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Your method for searching for all *.jpg files is little buggy. You should try this following approach instead. I've modified the code to check the code a little - but you'll get the idea.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion enableextensions
set count1=0
set count2=0
for /f %%f in ('Dir /s /b "Photo\*.jpg"') do set /a count1+=1
echo "1 " %count1%
for /f %%f in ('Dir /s /b "Photo\*.Png"') do set /a count2+=1
echo "2 " %count2%


if %count1% gtr %count2% (
    set /a count=%count2%-%count1%
    for /l %%A in (1,1,%count%) do echo "!count2! + %%A _1.jpg"
)
if %count2% gtr %count1% (
    set /a count=%count2%-%count1%
    for /l %%A in (1,1,%count%) do echo "!count1! + %%A _2.jpg"
)

endlocal
pause >nul
```

You can change the searching path from - "**Photo\*.jpg**" to anything in both cases. And this one has given me desired result on the CMD. I Hope this will work fine for you.

Comment: thanks the search is working fine. That's not my problem. It's counting the files. The problem is in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
echo "2 " %count2%

set /a count=count1-count2
set "count=%count:-=%"

if %count1% gtr %count2% (
...
```

You evidently want to calculate `count` and need a method to find its absolute value.

simply subtract one vale from the other, then replace any `-` in the result with *nothing*.

From the prompt, see `set /?` for documentation.